# Function is always false whenever I return true

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs

For some reason the console always says 'no'. I have tried to change all the returns to be true, yet it will still say 'no'

```
function checkLogin($http) {
  $http.get('http://localhost/api/v1/ping').
  then(function(response) {
    if(response.status === 200) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }, function() {
    return false;
  });

}
/**
 * @ngInject
 */
function loginController($scope, $location, $cookies, $http) {
  if(checkLogin($http) === true) {
    console.log('yes');
  } else {
    console.log('no');
    if($location.path() !== ''){

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sequence of events: 1 - checkLogin is called. 2 - Ajax request is sent. 3 - checkLogin returns. 4 - Ajax response is received. Pay attention: the function returns (3) **before** receiving the Ajax response (4).

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning any value out of `checkLogin` at all. And you *can't* return any value saying what the result of the check is, because `checkLogin` returns before it knows.

Your return statements are returning values *from the callback to `then`*. That call happens after `checkLogin` has returned.

Since you can't have `checkLogin` return `true`/`false` (since it doesn't know the answer), your best bet is probably to have it return a promise and resolevs with `true` or `false`. Amusing, you can do that simply by adding `return`::

```
function checkLogin($http) {
  return $http.get('http://localhost/api/v1/ping').
//^^^^^^
  then(function(response) {
    if(response.status === 200) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }, function() {
    return false;
  });
}
```

That works because `then` returns a new promise that will be fulfilled with what you return out of your `then` callback.

Then when you use it, use the promise.

```
function loginController($scope, $location, $cookies, $http) {
  checkLogin($http).
  then(function(loggedIn) {
    if(loggedIn) {
      console.log('yes');
    } else {
      console.log('no');
      if($location.path() !== ''){

      }
    }
  });
}
```

*(Tried to use your indentation style there, apologies if I didn't get it quite right.)*

Answer (score -1):

Callbacks, checklogin should receive a callback function as a parameter. Or you could work with promises, since they are used in $http